# Virtual Machine through Virtual Box when BootCamp pre-installed

Tags: bootcamp, virtualbox

I'm on a 13-inch Mid-2012 MacBook Pro, 8 GB RAM, 1 TB HDD, and I have BootCamp installed in it(Partition - 500GB). I am planning to install Kali Linux Virtual Machine through VirtualBox in the MacOS. I've downloaded it and imported it to VirtualBox.

I just wanted to ask whether installing it will affect BootCamp in any ways because the hard-drive is already partitioned for BootCamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Virtual Machines do not use a separate partitioning scheme, unlike Boot Camp. They're entirely file-based & sit on your existing Mac partition just like any other file.

Comment: Okay, and similar no harm if I install it on BootCamp, right?

Comment: That's an entirely different thing. Boot Camp is designed for Windows, nothing else.